# Angular 4 Radio form controll not working properly

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a radio button

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let item of shipping?.availableOptions">
     <input type="radio" name="shipping"  value="{{item.id}}" [checked]="orderCheckoutRequest?.order?.shippingOptionId===item.id" formControlName="shipping">
                                            {{item.name}} <strong>( {{item.shippingCost.amount}} {{item.shippingCost.currency | lowercase}} )</strong>

</div>
```

If i preselect this radio using [checked]="orderCheckoutRequest?.order?.shippingOptionId===item.id" radio button is indeed preselected, but angular form does not recognize it and form is invalid (because shipping option is required)

If i go another route and do something like this in my component:

```
const shippingControl = this.checkoutForm.get("shipping");
const selectedShippingOptionId = option['shippingOptionId'];
shippingControl.patchValue(selectedShippingOptionId);
```

Then for angular form this is valid, because control has a value, but i have 2 problems :

1. When i render the view in browser button is not selected at all
2. I trigger another http request because in ngOnInit() i have subscribed to shippingControl like this :

   `shippingControl.valueChanges.skip(1).subscribe(data => { 
   this.cartService.updateShippingForOrder();
   })`

I have tried fixing this problem with skip(1) but this is not honored at all for some reason.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Push one flag , say "radioSelected" to `shipping?.availableOptions` array.
By default set its value to false.
Once `orderCheckoutRequest?.order?.shippingOptionId===item.id` 
   satisfies, then update the corresponding "radioSelected" value to true.

Change the html template `[checked]` with

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping"  value="{{item.id}}" [checked]="item.radioSelected" formControlName="shipping">
```